# Recreate the Sequence

Tags: algorithm, integer, sequence

I came across the following problem, which has been on my mind ever since:

Alice has written `N` consecutive, positive integers on a blackboard. E.g. `"99, 100, 101, 102"`. Bob has erased all digits, but one, from each number, so the sequence now reads e.g. `"9, 0, 0, 1"`. Notice that the digit he leaves over can be a different one for every integer.

Our task is, in `O(N log N`) time complexity, to find the smallest number that may have started the sequence. In the above example the answer would be `99`. For the length 7 sequence `"1, 4, 0, 5, 4, 1, 4"` , the answer would be `1042`. (Which yield the sequence 1042, 1043, 1044, 1045, 1046, 1047, 1048).

I can show an upper bound up of around `1234567890*N`, so the output can't be of unlimited size. However I haven't been able to even find an efficient `O(N^2)` solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: "I can show an upper bound up of around 1234567890*N" what do you mean by that? that for all possible inputs, the result is smaller than 1234567890*N?

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought only the last digit was left over, but that's not the case.

Comment: Yes, you don't know if the digit you get comes from 'start', 'middle' or 'end' of the original number. Hence a sequence starting 1023456789001, 1023456789002, ... could be represented by any list of single digits.

Comment: Is it just random digit erased?

Comment: @AlmaDo I think *arbitrary* would be the better term. Bob is an adversary that deletes whichever digits he prefers, possibly to make it especially hard

Comment: So it's "for all members M-th digit is saved", where `M` isn't  known (but is same for all members) ?

Comment: @AlmaDo No. Look at the example

Comment: @NiklasB. from sample I see that from each member of sequence we saved random digit (somewhere first, somewhere second e t.c.)

Comment: @AlmaDo Yes, exactly. But the term *random* has a very specific meaning in mathematics that does not apply here, which is why I suggested *arbitrary*

Comment: Can you tell us the source of this problem? Are you positive it's solvable in O(N log N)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATE:** For those interested, this problem appeared in the [Baltic Olympiad in Informatics (BOI) 2014](http://www.boi2014.lmio.lt/tasks.html) (it's the task "Sequence"). [Due to Codeforces user Fdg](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/12222#comment-168447), here's an O(N log N) solution: Try every possible last digit of the starting value. Partition contiguous array elements into groups that have the digits 0 to 9 at the end (this can be inferred from the starting value's last digit). We know that all values in the same group have the same prefix, after we remove their last digit. Let's eliminate all those values where the digit in the input matches the last digit that it *should* have according to their position.

Now we have a slightly different subproblem: For every group of 10, we know a *set* of digits that appear in its prefix. We collapse this into a single array element. This generalized problem only has one tenth the size of the original problem and can be solved using the same algorithm, recursively.

We thus get the recurrence T(N) = 10 * T(N / 10) + O(N), which we solve as T(N) = O(N log N) using the master theorem.

**Example:**

Let's say the input is `[1, 4, 0, 5, 4, 1, 4, 9, 5, 0, 1, 0]`. So in the generalized form, we know the following subsets of digits for every position:

```
{1} {4} {0} {5} {4} {1} {4} {9} {5} {0} {1} {0}
```

We check the number `2` as the last digit of the starting number (of course we check all the other digits too, but this branch will turn out to contain the minimum solution). We know that the sequence of last digits goes like

```
2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  1  2  3
```

So we know the groups that have the same prefix (2-9 and 0-3). We also eliminate those digits from the sets that we already know are at the correct position:

```
{1} {4} {0} {} {4} {1} {4} {} | {5} {0} {1} {0}
```

By collecting all the digits of each group, we arrive at the reduced problem

```
{0,1,4} {0,1,5}
```

Again we brute-force the second to last digit. Let's say we are checking `4`. We get:

```
  4     5
{0,1} {0,1}
```

Which reduces to

```
{0,1}
```

Now that we are down to only one array element, we just have to build the lexicographically smallest number out of those digits that has no leading zeroes, which is `10`. So the result is `1042`.

#### Old version

I believe one key observation here is that in a progression like this, of length N, only the last ceil(log_10(N)) digits are changed more than once. So we could brute-force the last ceil(log_10(N)) digits, the number of nines at the end of the prefix and the digit before that in O(N * log N).

So we fix the pattern

```
P..PX9..9S...S
```

where the suffix S is known, the number of nines is known, X < 9 is known, but the prefix P is not.

We can now remove those numbers from the sequence that already match one of the digits we already know appears at their respective position. We are left with a set of digits which we know comprise the prefix P. We just form the lexicographically smallest string that has no leading zeroes and contains all the digits.

The runtime is O(N^2 log N).

Comment: This does not guarantee the smallest number possible, since you can remove _D[j]-D[i] mod 10 = j-i_, as I suggested in my answer.

Comment: @Nick We seem to misunderstand each other. My suggestion is to enumerate *all* candidates in a systematic way, so of course you will find the smallest solution as well. The trick is how to bring the set of candidates down to a manageable size

Comment: I thought that's exactly what you should not do if you want to reach _N log N_ runtime.

Comment: @Nick I just showed that the runtime of this is O(N^2 log N). It's not O(N log N), but it's a start because it's polynomial in N

Comment: How do you determine the last log(N) digits? maximize the length sequence for each digit?

Comment: @PhamTrung My suggestion here is to try every combination, there are only O(10^ceil(log_10(N))) = O(N). Not sure how to do it better

Comment: I think this is correct. Though it might be a bit tricky to implement the prefix given it can still change once. The `logN` can probably be achieved by eliminating duplicates in the 'blocks' as we go up the digits. E.g. for digit 3 we can group digits together in blocks of thousands which have the same prefix, but there can only be ten possibilities for that digit. Actually this might end up giving `N+N/10+N/100+... = O(N)`. Nice!

Comment: @ThomasAhle Yes, X might change at exactly one position, but you know exactly where if you know S. I'm unclear how you plan to get the transition down to o(N) (that is a little-o). E.g. for input `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,...]` for every tenth candidate suffix the set of removed array elements changes entirely from empty to full

Comment: Ah, and P does not change at all, so it's easy to construct if you know the set of its digits. Only keep in mind that you can't have leading zeroes

Comment: @ThomasAhle I think you already got the right idea, but I updated the answer with the O(N log N) algorithm.

Comment: Great job; thank you so much for having editted your answer with the source and another solution. This one deserves more upvotes!

Comment: @Bentoy13 Well it's [algorithm], not the best place to collect votes :)

Comment: @NiklasB. I'd have +1'd for that reason alone ;) life's hard out here in [algorithm] ;)